# Twilio test credentials logs

Tags: testing, twilio

Is there a way of seeing the logs of your Twilio test credentials?

I am using my test credentials for testing, and I would like to know if my test messages are sent.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of test credentials is that the messages are *not* sent, unfortunately. They can be used to test your app without charging money to your account. Hence, you only get the HTTP response from using them, and no messages are sent to anyone's phone.

Comment: The test credentials will also *not* leave any updates or information in your logs.. including the error/notification logs.

Comment: I understand that they are not sent. Other service, such as Mandrill, still provide you a user interface to see logs of your test credentials usage.
It provides you an easy way to verify that the message are sent exactly as you wanted.
Could be a nice feature.

Comment: I'm running into this as well. If I'm testing an SMS app with Twilio Test Credentials, is there really no way to view, for example, the text of the messages sent and received?

Comment: Twilio still (as of July 16, 2016) does NOT log messages if you're using Test Credentials. Their support team told me: "Test messages will not show in the logs; only charged transactions do."  I'm very disappointed.

Comment: Other great API's like Stripe's have an admin test experience that mirrors the admin production experience. Seems like a missing feature for Twilio.

Comment: Amazing there's no test credentials log in 2021.